# How should I format a date to always respect the specified format?

Tags: datetime, go

I have a Go API that is supposed to return a timestamp in the following format (Java notation but should be understandable):

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'
```

My Go API will build this timestamp as follows:

```
func ParseToTimestamp(duration string, systemTime time.Time) (string, error) {
    parsedDuration, err := time.ParseDuration(duration)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    validity := systemTime.Add(parsedDuration)
    return validity.Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999Z"), nil
}
```

I've noticed, however, that this formatted string is not always respecting the wished format. For example, if I pass a date which has 0 nano-seconds:

```
duration := "10m"
systemTime := time.Date(1990, time.January, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC) //no nano-seconds
timestamp, _ := fxcash.ParseToTimestamp(duration, systemTime)
fmt.Println(timestamp)
>> 1990-01-24T00:10:00Z
```

However, if I pass a date which has 120k nano-seconds:

```
duration := "10m"
systemTime := time.Date(1990, time.January, 24, 0, 0, 0, 120000, time.UTC) //120k nano-seconds
timestamp, _ := fxcash.ParseToTimestamp(duration, systemTime)
fmt.Println(timestamp)
>> 1990-01-24T00:10:00.00012Z
```

Generally speaking, this causes an issue because the service that consumes my Go output expects to have exactly 6 nano-seconds, even if they were only zeros `.000000Z`.

Is there a way to do that without heavy parsing/ugly splitting using standard Go Libraries?

Sorry if this question is basic but I'm very new to Go, I've looked for examples on the web but couldn't find any.

Comment: From the `time` package docs: `If the fraction in the layout is 9s, trailing zeros are dropped`, use `.000000` as shown in the format examples.